# Why can't I create a generic function?

Tags: generics, types, f#

In the code below the compiler assumes that argument r is of type Rec2. Since type Rec1 has all the fields used in the function definition, one can create a function where r is of type Rec1 using a function annotation. So far, so good.

But I want r to be of another type, say 'a. Unfortunately I don't know what 'a is. So I tried to create a generic function with r being of a generic type. The code below shows the compiler did not let me do it.

Is there a way to create such a generic function?

```
type Rec1 = {A: int; B: string}
let r0 = {A = 0; B = "Hello"}
type Rec2 = {A: int; B: string; C: float}

let f2 (x, r) = {A = r.A; B = r.B; C = x}
// val f2 : x:float * r:Rec2 -> Rec2
let f1 (x, (r: Rec1)) = {A = r.A; B = r.B; C = x}
// val f1 : x:float * r:Rec1 -> Rec2
let g<'T> (x, (r: 'T)) = {A = r.A; B = r.B; C = x}
(* error FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    'T    
is not compatible with type
    Rec2    
The type ''T' does not match the type 'Rec2' *)
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Your generic type is not any type, it should have two fields named A and B, so you need to be able to specify that restriction. You can use static constraints to read the values in a generic way but not to create the record in a generic way.

Comment: Because the short answer is no, that's not how generics work. And the long answer is yes, but you don't want to do that.

Comment: @Gustavo - I actually have a type with two fields named A and B, but I do not know its name. It is the type of a row in an object created by a  Csv Provider and I cannot determine its signature so as to insert it in a type annotation.

Comment: @Soldalma: Provided types are static, so they're available for use in type annotations. That's the whole point of type providers. See the answer to your other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments reveal that you are actually working with the CSVProvider, which means you don't need to do this.  You have static typing already:

Using the example csv file in the FSharp.Data documentation:

> Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
>   2012-01-27,29.45,29.53,29.17,29.23,44187700,29.23
>   2012-01-26,29.61,29.70,29.40,29.50,49102800,29.50
>   2012-01-25,29.07,29.65,29.07,29.56,59231700,29.56
>   2012-01-24,29.47,29.57,29.18,29.34,51703300,29.34

Just use `Stocks.Row` as the type:

```
type Stocks = CsvProvider<"test.csv">

type Rec2 = {Open: decimal; Close: decimal; Extra: string}

let openCloseWithExtra (stockRow : Stocks.Row) =
    {Open = stockRow.Open; Close = stockRow.Close; Extra = "extra"}
```

---

If, for some reason, you did need to work with a completely arbitrary type that exposed two properties, you could do it using statically resolved type parameters:

```
let inline anyOpenCloseWithExtra stockRow =
    let open' = ((^T) : (member Open : decimal) (stockRow))
    let close' = ((^T) : (member Close : decimal) (stockRow))
    {Open = open'; Close = close'; Extra = "extra"}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how did you find Stocks.Row was the type? I mean, is there a procedure I could have followed to find that Stocks.Row was the type?

Comment: @Soldalma Probably the most obvious thing to do is look at the type of `Stocks.GetSample().Rows`, you'll see it's listed as `seq<CsvProvider<...>.Row>` so you know that each element has type `CsvProvider<...>.Row`, i.e. `Stocks.Row` in this case.

Comment: I had done this but I did not figure out that `CsvProvider<...>` meant `Stocks`, the name of the CsvProvider.